# Formatação WindRose Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Olá, gostaria que meu gráfico windrose apresentasse a mesma porcentagem para ambos os plots, e também que a legenda fosse única e centralizada, alguém conseguiria me ajudar?
Segue o código:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="windrose")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection="windrose")

ax1.bar(vm['direção'],vm['vel'],normed=True, bins=np.arange(0.01,9,2), cmap=cm.RdYlBu_r)
ax1.set_legend()
ax1.set_title('Rosa dos Ventos - Manhã')

ax2.bar(vt['direção'],vt['vel'],normed=True, bins=np.arange(0.01,9,2), cmap=cm.RdYlBu_r)
ax2.set_legend()
ax2.set_title('Rosa dos Ventos - Tarde')
```

e o resultado:
[image: WindRose]